# PHP download image using header

Tags: php, download, header, jpeg

I'm really new to php and web coding in general. I'm trying to offer an image for download via php. What additional code do I need to make this happen? I've tried googling it and searching on here and, whilst I know this question has been asked and answered before, reading the answers is making my inexperienced head spin. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
public function ExportUserImage()
    {
        $image = $this->user->image;

        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="avatar.jpg"');
        $outstream = fopen($image,'w'); // Not sure if this is right 
        //>>don't know what I need here<<
        fclose($outstream);

    }
```

Comment: `echo($image)`or `echo($outstream)` should do the trick.

Comment: do I need the outstream / fopen if I use `echo($image)`?

- also thank you for your reply

Comment: you want to download the image avatar.jpg?which is present in the same folder. I am i right ?

Comment: No I just want the Image which I have a selector for to be downloaded with the filename avatar.jpg

Comment: @AlecGamble if ècho($image)` works you don't need it

Comment: http://php.net/readfile And is $image a PATH to your image, or is it the actual image's binary data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just missed out to actually give out the image stream, which should be downloaded.

You can simple echo out the $image, no need to open a filestream for it, because you set your headers right.

```
public function ExportUserImage()
    {
        $image = $this->user->image;

        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="avatar.jpg"');
        echo $image;

    }
```